# make some column not editable in editable data-table

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, rest

I have a web app, frontend using HTML5, backend using Django.

I have an editable table in HTML5.

But the use need to make some columns not editable.

I could only set the editable flag on the table basis, not sure how to set it on the column basis, as my table do not have a table body(call restful API to render the table body).

How could I make some column of the table not editable?

```
           <table contenteditable='true' class="table table-bordered table-sm" width="100%" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 1.0rem;"
               id="bk-table"
               data-toggle="table"
               data-toolbar="#toolbar"
               data-cookie="true"
               data-cookie-id-table="materialId"
               data-show-columns="true"
               data-show-refresh="true"
               data-show-fullscreen="true"
               data-show-export="true"
               data-height="650"
               data-click-to-select="true"
               data-id-field="id"
               data-show-footer="true"
               data-url="/api/materials/"
               data-query-params="queryParams"
               data-remember-order="true"
               data-pagination="true"
               data-side-pagination="client"
               {# data-side-pagination="server" #}
               data-total-field="count"
               data-data-field="results">
            <colgroup>
                <col span="3" style="background-color:white">
                <col span="5"  style="background-color:#e8ecfd">
                <col span="1" style="background-color:white">
                <col span="7"  style="background-color:#e8ecfd">
            </colgroup>
            <thead class="thead-dark" >
            <tr >
                <!--th  data-sortable="true" >ID</th-->
                <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
                <th data-field="courseCode"  data-formatter="renderCourse">Course Code</th>
                <th data-field="type">Course Type</th>
                <th class ='title'  data-field="book.title">Course Material Title</th>
                <th class ='author'  name="Author" data-field="book.author">Author/Editor</th>
                <th class ='pub_date'  name="pub_date" data-field="book.pub_date">Publication Year</th>
                <th class ='edition' data-field="book.edition">Edition + Special Edition</th>
                <th class ='publisher' data-field="book.publisher">Publisher</th>
                <th class ='isbn' data-field="book.isbn">iSBN or e-iSBN/VBID</th>
                <th class ='Format_issued' data-field="book.Format_issued">Material Format</th>
                <th class ='Purchase_Price' data-field="book.e_price_cur">eText SUSS Price Currency</th>
                <th class ='Total_StockAndWrap' data-field="book.e_price">eText SUSS Price</th>
                <th class ='Distribution_platform' data-field="book.Distribution_platform">Distribution Mode</th>
                <th class ='Discard_Status' data-field="status">Book Status</th>
                <th class ='discard_reason' data-field="discard_reason">Discard Reason</th>
                <th data-field="remark">Remarks</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

restapi:

```
class MaterialSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
book = BookSerializer(many=False)
course = CourseSerializer(many=False)
courseId = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='course.courseInfo.id')
year = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='course.semester.year')
month = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='course.semester.month')
term = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='course.semester.term')
quota = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='course.quota')
course_title = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='course.courseInfo.title')
type = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='course.courseInfo.type')
available = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='course.courseInfo.available')
postgraduate = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='course.courseInfo.postgraduate')
Presentation_Pattern = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='course.courseInfo.pattern')
discipline = DisciplineSerializer(source='course.courseInfo.discipline')
retail_price_display = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='book.retail_price_display')
cover = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='book.cover')




courseCode = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_courseCode(self, obj):
    return f'{obj.course.courseInfo.discipline_code}{obj.course.courseInfo.code}'

class Meta:
    model = Material
    fields = ['id', 'book', 'course', 'course_title', 'type','school', 'available', 'postgraduate', 'courseCode', 'courseId', 'year', 'month', 'term', 'quota',
              'modified', 'discipline', 'remark', 'status', 'is_discard', 'discard_reason', 'retail_price_display', 'Presentation_Pattern','cover']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same contenteditable attribute and set it to false. Although setting it on the `<th>` elements will not also set it on all the `<td>` elements in that column in tbody. You have to set contenteditable to false on every `<td>` in that column like:

```
<td contenteditable="false">Content</td>
```

Can you modify the restful API's render function to set the attribute?

Comment: how to set td attribute in rest api? I have posted my API

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by adding flags in Django models.
Add is_editable flag with default value as True. Based on this flag you can hide the edit button and also restrict users by editing this data through URL ID.

In **MaterialSerializer** model add `is_editable = models.BooleanField(default=True)`
Based on this flag you can hide/un-hide the edit functionality for the users.

Comment: But the user mainly want to let the table cells not editable for those non-editable items. How could I make the table cell not editable?